# Android NDK INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI support

Tags: android

I have application that has Library project in it that contains ndk code.
The Library code is trigger after a button press.
The problem is when I'm want to install the application on Galaxy Ace I get the following Error INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE.
I understand that the device CPU doesn't support NDK, but I want to be able to install the application and I will prevent the Library from running.
any ideas?? 
Thank's
david

Comment: don't list that ABI in manifest?

Comment: I listed the armeabi-v7a on the Application.mk

Comment: I suspect if you are going to package NDK libraries at all, you are going to have to include one compatible with every ABI you want to be installable on.  Technically you could package the libraries as arbitrary data and copy them out to private storage with the executable flag set yourself, but that seems like a lot of effort to work around generally well-intentioned system behavior.  How about making a dummy library full of do-nothing functions?

Comment: Good Idea!!! I listed APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a armeabi x86 and added a dummy armeabi so files that was taken from armeabi-v7a. so I could run my application and denied the library start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved I listed APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a armeabi x86 and added a dummy armeabi so files to libs folder that was taken from armeabi-v7a. so I could run my application and denied the library start